# Problems in setting a date constraint on a parse query

Tags: javascript, date, parse-platform, constraints

I'm trying to make a parse query and put a date constraint on the query via javascript API.

This is the `Result` table/object (on parse.com) which I'm making a query for:
[image: My "table": <code>Result</code>]

```
Column                  Data type
```

```
objectId                String
createdDate             Date
updatedAt               Date
obtainedPonts           Number
relatedDriver           Relation
relatedTest             Relation
ACL                     ACL
resultCeasesToBeValid   Date
didPassTheTest          Boolean
```

Some example data from `resultCeasesToBeValid`:

[image: Example data from <code>resultCeasesToBeValid</code>]

This is my goal: I want the query to give me a set of `Result` where today < `resultCeasesToBeValid`.

My problem is that I always recieve an `Result` array with .length = 0 when I'm trying to put date constraints on the query.

```
function IsApprovedAndHasValidResults(currentDriverObjectId) {

    var Driver = Parse.Object.extend('Driver');
    var currentDriverObject = new Driver();
    currentDriverObject.id = currentDriverObjectId;

    var queryResult = new Parse.Query(Result);

    //set the constraints
    queryResult.equalTo('relatedDriver', currentDriverObject); //this constraint works as expected

    /****************************************************************************************************
    *var today = new Date();         // "today" is as time of writing 3 oct 2014                        *
    *                                                                                                   *
    *  //will give me a parseResults[] of .length=0:                                                    *
    *queryResult.lessThan('resultCeasesToBeValid', today);                                              *
    *                                                                                                   *
    * //will give me a parseResults[] of .length=0:                                                     *
    *queryResult.lessThan('resultCeasesToBeValid', { "__type": "Date", "iso": today.toISOString() });   *
    *                                                                                                   *
    *****************************************************************************************************/

    queryResult.find({
        success: function (parseResults) {
            // results is an array of Parse.Object.
        /*when the code gets here parseResults array.lenght equals 0*/
        },

        error: function (error) {
            // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        /*will never be here*/  
        }
    });
}
```

Other developers seem to have the same problem, [user Abhishek suspects a bug](https://www.parse.com/questions/date-query-constraints).  According to [Héctor Ramos (Parse)](https://www.parse.com/questions/javascript-query-using-greaterthan-createdat), long time ago: "You should use a Date object, not a string, when dealing with dates in JavaScript.". Obviously this doesn't work!

Is my code wrong in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

```
queryResult._where.resultCeasesToBeValid = {'$lt' :{ "__type": "Date", "iso": today}}};
```

`_where` is a "private property" though and i wouldn't rely on it too much. Parse should fix this.

If you can [change the column type], i would suggest storing the date as a unix timestamp to avoid this kind of issues:

```
var timestamp = +new Date();
result.save({'resultCeasesToBeValid': timestamp});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the tip, I'll try the timestamp!

Comment: That was it! I believe that the date-constraint bug still exists (more than two years after it was reported!)

Thanks for the great workaround! I changed to [timestamp].